# Why is this voltage follower not working in Proteus?

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, power

I have a 4th order bandpass filter which needs to be biased using 1/2 Vcc. I am trying to achieve this using a voltage follower. The bandpass filter was constructed using Multiple feedback topology as shown:

[image]

On Proteus I get a 100kHz center frequency and a 4kHz band pass at a gain of 1 AV.

Using a +2.5V simulation goes as expected, and gives the desired response.

[image]

[image]

I designed two voltage followers using LM324, and tested these in a separate project. I get 2.5V output as expected.

On adding the voltage followers, and connecting just one output of the voltage follower to the second stage of the op-amp, simulation still takes place without errors, but the response is not correct, as I need to bias both stages.

[image]

On connecting both voltage followers, I get an error. I cant understand why.

[image]

[image]

Any suggestions why this is happening would be appreciated.

Comment: What is difference between #2 and #3 diagrams?

Comment: @analogsystemsrf, output of LM324 in #2 is only connected to the second stage of the filter. In #3, U1:A is also connected.

Comment: There's a lot of problems with this design and no specs. results indicate low Q and -40dB @ 85kHz on my sim ... meanwhile ground noise is 60dB gain above signal . What are your specs??????  Is this for WPT? (hunch)

Comment: Updated question with current response. Center freq is @100kHz, as was calculated. Any suggestions on how I can reduce ground noise?

Comment: Yes dont use R7/R55 ratios ... What shape is the passband ( Cauer, Bessel, )?  or in otherwords, what is the stop band attenuation

Comment: Then what cap tolerances can you afford?

Comment: I am using Butterworth approximation with a stop-band attenuation of 30dB. Could you provide some source on where I can calculate cap tolerances for the above specs? I can't seem to find anything. Thank you

Comment: @Rrz0 the non-inverting input of the second opamp isnt connected to anything in the third figure...

Answer (score 1):

The lousy old LM324 has slew rate problems above a few kHz. It also has hardly any open-loop gain at 100khz. Your circuit needs the output of the LM324 to have a low impedance but it can't do it at 100kHz. You need a fast opamp to work at 100kHz.

Comment: Or just AC couple the signal and connect R55 and R3 to ground. Then U6 and U2 + inputs can be biased with resistor dividers, and U1 A and B aren't required.

Answer (score 0):

There are better design tools now.  TI is releasing an upgraded online filter designer with a tolerance stackup that is now critical with Q > 10 here >25.

- Don't duplicate a 2nd order filter to make a 4th order filter when you can get better results for passband ripple and stopband skirt attenuation or linear phase or maximally flat group delay or etc.
- Sallen & Keys filters **are preferred** for high Q but uses an extra R but at the advantage of much lower R ratios and common C values. More important is that the input is not severely attenuated and ground noise severely amplified even when unity gain overall.

[image]  Consider your specs wisely. Be critical about tolerances and costs.

- Unity gain tolerance error can be -1.5 dB even with 0.5% R and 2% C
  [image]